# How to retrieve the last command's return value in TCL interpreter?

Tags: tcl, read-eval-print-loop

In Tcl, if I evaluate a command, and my expression failed to store the result in a variable, other than reevaluating the command, is there a way to retrieve the last command's return value in a TCL interpreter?  For example, in some lisps, the variable `*` is bound to the result of the last evaluation, is there something like that in TCL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Tcl interpreter loop — which is pretty simple minded, with very few hidden features — *doesn't* save the last result value for you; it assumes that if you want to save that for later, you'll do so manually (or you'll repeat the command and get the result anew so you can save it then).

If you want to save a value for later, use `set`. You can use `*` as the name of the variable (it is legal) but it's annoying in practice because the `$var` syntax shortcut doesn't work with it and instead you'd need to do:

```
% set * [expr {2**2**2**2}]; # Or whatever...
65536
% puts "the value was ${*}... this time!"
the value was 65536... this time!
% puts "an alternative is to do [set *]"
an alternative is to do 65536
```

This will probably be a bit annoying when typing; use a name like `it` instead.

```
% set it [expr {2**2**2**2}]; # Or whatever...
65536
% puts [string length [expr {123 << $it}]]
19731
```

(That last number has rather a lot of digits in it, more than I expected…)

Answer (score 0):

> For example, in some lisps, the variable * is bound to the result of
>   the last evaluation, is there something like that in TCL?

It depends, but in the non-error case, [`catch`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/catch.htm) can be used to, well, catch the result of the last successful evaluation within the enclosed script:

```
proc foo {} {return FOO}
proc bar {} {return BAR}

if {![catch {
    if {rand() < 0.5} {foo} else {bar}
} * opts]} {
    # handle result of last cmd evaluation
    puts ${*}
} else {
    # handle an error
    puts [dict get $opts -errorinfo]
}
```

If you happen to know the command names in advance, [command traces](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/trace.htm#M11) might be another option.